# Increment dictionary value in class __init__?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to create a class that gets a poll question and voting options and returns the total votes for each option in a list of tuples. However, I cannot get the dictionary I set in `__init__` to keep the votes of previous instances.

Here is my code:

```
class Poll:
    def __init__(self, question, options):
        self.question = question
        self.options = options
        self.votes = {}

    def vote(self, option):
        if option in self.votes:
            self.votes[option] += 1
        else: 
            self.votes[option] = 1
        return True

    def get_votes(self):
        vote_list = [(key, value) for key, value in self.votes.items()]
        return vote_list


vote_1 = Poll("What is your favorite fruit?", ["Apple", "Banana"])
vote_1.vote("Apple")
vote_2 = Poll("What is your favorite fruit?", ["Apple", "Banana"])
vote_2.vote("Banana")
vote_3 = Poll("What is your favorite fruit?", ["Apple", "Banana"])
vote_3.vote("Apple")
print(vote_1.get_votes())
print(vote_2.get_votes())
print(vote_3.get_votes())
```

This is what I get:

```
[('Apple', 1)]
[('Banana', 1)]
[('Apple', 1)]
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
[('Apple', 1]
[('Apple', 1), ('Banana', 1)]    
[('Apple', 2), ('Banana', 1)]
```

I cannot set the 'vote' function to return the vote because it has to return `True`.

I think I need another function to hold the dictionary but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You are creating separate poll instances. You want a single poll instance and then add all three votes to the same poll.

Comment: @alaniwi thanks. I need get one vote at a time. This is how the exercise is designed.

Comment: FWIW, you can simplify `get_votes`: `return list(self.votes.items())`

Comment: @clnns45 You can still call `get_votes()` after each vote if you want. I've edited my anwer to reflect this.

Comment: Also FWIW you could look into [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its method `most_common` for simplifying your class. And `Poll.vote` should probably check that `option in self.options`.

Answer (score 3):

The code is nearly correct.  The `Poll` class itself is fine, but you are then instantiating it separately for each vote, instead of calling the `vote` method on the same instance each time.  All you need to do is this:

```
poll = Poll("What is your favorite fruit?", ["Apple", "Banana"])
poll.vote("Apple")
print(poll.get_votes())
poll.vote("Banana")
print(poll.get_votes())
poll.vote("Apple")
print(poll.get_votes())
```

although you could also consider using a loop, rather than repeating code:

```
poll = Poll("What is your favorite fruit?", ["Apple", "Banana"])
for option in "Apple", "Banana", "Apple":
    poll.vote(option)
    print(poll.get_votes())
```

---

By the way, the one improvement that I would suggest to the `Poll` class (although not directly related to the question) is that the `options` is not really being used, beyond assigning it to `self.options` that is then not used.  You could use it inside the `vote` method to enforce that people do not vote on something which is not one of the options.  For example, if the method started with:

```
    def vote(self, option):
        if option not in self.options:
            raise ValueError("you are not allowed to vote on {}"
                             .format(option))        
        # do other stuff
```

and then after instantiating using:

```
poll = Poll("What is your favorite fruit?", ["Apple", "Banana"])
```

you did:

```
poll.vote("Cheese")
```

then this would raise an exception.

Comment: thank you very much, changing the creation of the instance has done the trick!